# How to test if value is present in Set of objects with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

I'm trying to figure out how to see if a specific value, in this case "/db/User/10" exists in a set of objects that is returned from an API.

The Data returned from the API from console.log(test)

```
Set {
  Object {
    "UserData": "/db/UserData/509c404f-ffa1-49d3-a161-b9eb5b2ebb14",
    "UserDataPrivate": "/db/UserDataPrivate/26b7d879-4403-4135-ab44-b23e5244606b",
    "UserStatus": "/db/UserStatus/cb50eae0-e254-4d8c-915a-674fd314fff3",
    "createdAt": "2017-10-20T21:03:26.575Z",
    "id": "/db/User/68",
    "inactive": null,
    "updatedAt": "2017-10-20T23:34:12.179Z",
    "username": "15031111234",
    "version": 4,
  },
  Object {
    "UserData": "/db/UserData/a3dded63-4e0b-4841-b201-4c96dad1844d",
    "UserDataPrivate": "/db/UserDataPrivate/6037a718-e33f-4945-b2d0-ca4c11fa4f13",
    "UserStatus": null,
    "createdAt": "2017-09-21T18:26:31.089Z",
    "id": "/db/User/10",
    "inactive": false,
    "updatedAt": "2017-10-18T20:10:06.681Z",
    "username": "15038304313",
    "version": 19,
  },
}

var searchbyID = propEq('id', '/db/User/10');
result = filter(searchbyID, test);
console.log(result)
```

I'm thinking this should return true, but instead, it returns an empty array.

Is this the right approach with Ramda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the Set to an Array.

```
var searchbyID = propEq('id', '/db/User/10');
result = filter(searchbyID, Array.from(test));
console.log(result)
```

It won't return true, but objects that match. You could be wanting `find` instead.